# 2017 Nissan Altima Bluetooth On/Off

Tags: nissan, audio, altima, bluetooth

I just purchased a 2017 Nissan Altima and I was able to pair my iPhone 8 to the Bluetooth, however every time I start my car the Bluetooth feature on my car is off. So if I want to utilize the Bluetooth features in my car I have to turn it on (in my car- not my phone) every single time I start my car. Is there a way to make this stay on so I don't have to turn it on every single time? I don't ever have to do anything different with my phone. I have tried unpairing the phone and pairing it again but the car's Bluetooth feature still has to be turned on every time I start my car.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I just bought the same car this week. Did you ever figure this out?